# Delete tasks from a HTTP Request

Tags: flow, power-automate, ms-project, project-online, pwa

I need to create a Automated flow to delete a Project Online Task, with specific criteria, like name or Start date.

I couldn't find any method on Internet for a HTTP Request.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is a limitation set by Microsoft - many people have been raising their voices to enable this deletion feature in the Microsoft user voice forum.

One of the users comments added below:

"You can create buckets, list buckets but not delete them. Why oh why Microsoft? Are you protecting us from ourselves? Please don't

You can create tasks, list tasks, update tasks, but not delete them??? Please undumbify your software."

Reference thread:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Flow-delete-tasks-in-planner/idi-p/115930